# Perfective-imperfective aspectual system

Tags: slavic-languages, aspect

I'm reading Dahl's article on aspect where it says that some of the major aspectual types are 1) progressive 2) habitual 3) completive 4) imperfective - perfective.

I'm wondering if there's a language that has not only type 4 but also a more detailed division within it. If there is one, how is it all expressed morphologically?

P.S. Proto-Slavic inherited the distinction between Aorist and Imperfect but later a new aspectual system emerged so that a "perfective imperfect" verbal form was possible. Is there anyone who can provide some examples for it? I'm quite clueless as to what such forms could mean.

Comment: How about Ancient Greek, where the primary aspect distinctions were between "ongoing action", "completed action", and "action at a single point in time"? Does that count?

Comment: Does your question about examples of perfective / imperfective mean that you don't understand how the distinction operates in Slavic?

Comment: @user6726 I am a Russian native speaker and there's only perfective/imperfective as far as i know. The article I'm reading makes a point referring to Old Church Slavonic where imperfective was attested with aorist. Is it more or less like the verb приходить in russian but more morphologically explicit?

Comment: @Draconis I'm not sure, but I'd appreciate if you could exemplify the aspects of Ancient Greek